# How can I spread custom object through my MVC application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, concurrency, webforms

Let say I have an object that is similar for each user that try to access to my website.
A sort of Session Scope object, which should be visible on every View/Model/Controller inside my whole "application".

I'd like to create it when I call a page and populate it through data coming from my own database.

Than, on View (as example) calling myObject.Title.
On WebForms I'm doing this extending a class of the UserControl, such as:

```
public class iUserControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected MyCurrentPage myCurrentPage;

    public iUserControl()
    {

    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        myCurrentPage = new MyCurrentPageWrapper();
    }
}
```

than, for each UserControl, somethings like this:

```
public partial class context_pippo_MyOwnUserControl : iUserControl
```

on MVC I can't see any extension for each controls, so how can I could achieve this kind of process? I'd like to get rid about storing elements on Session.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand question correctly, I think I've done something similar in one project.
I had something like this:

```
public interface IControllerBaseService 
{
   IUserService UserService {get;set;}
   ShoppingMode ShoppingMode {get;set;}
   ...
}

public abstract class ControllerBase : Controller, IControllerBaseService 
{
   public IUserService UserService {get;set;} // this is injected by IoC
   public ShoppingMode ShoppingMode 
   {
      get 
      {
           return UserService.CurrentShoppingMode; // this uses injected instance to get value
      }
   ...
}
```

As long, as I user IoC container to create controller instances, UserService property is injected by container.

You can access now your interface from view like this:

```
(IControllerBaseService)ViewContext.Controller
```

To have a shortcuts for most common used properties in `IControllerBaseService`, I had several extension methods, something like this:

```
 public static ShoppingMode CurrentShoppingMode(this HtmlHelper helper)
 {
     return ((IContollerBaseService)helper.ViewContext.Controller).ShoppingMode;
 }
```

So in view it looked like `@Html.CurrentShoppingMode()`

Comment: Let say I have `FamilyComponents` class, which I should access to it wherever I want (on each View): where do I create the single instance of `FamilyComponents`? Inside the ControllerBase? Can you give to me a smart example? Thank you

Comment: I've updated my answer a bit, but in general if I have complex property in IControllerBaseService, it is either injected by IoC container, either resolved using injected properties, as in example.